# Networkx: how use out_edges() in a graph with properties in the nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

I use networkx library

I need to use the out_edges in a MultiDiGraph graph. When I use it in empty nodes works well:

```
g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(3,4),(1,6)])
g.out_edges(1)
```

Out:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 6)]
```

But if put attributes in nodes:

```
g[1]["foo"] = "fighter"
```

It crashes:

```
g.out_edges(1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was setting the attributes in the wrong way. This is the correct way:
    g.node[1]["foo"] = "fighter"